# how to filter a column based on data from other column? ( Edit: attached image for understanding)

Tags: google-sheets

[image]I have dates on A2:A6000  and some values ranging from  -6 to +6 on corresponding G3:G6000.

I would like to get the dates noted whenever the values in corresponding G column is less than -4 (i.e. -4to-6) & whenever it is greater than 4 i.e. (4 to 6).

I would like to get those specific dates autoed on a separate column. how to do it on google sheets.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show some example of your data with expected output, hard to know from your wording.

Comment: Use Filter or Query function.

Comment: @KinSiang i have added the image for better understanding.

Comment: What you've explained in your post and what is shown/explained in your image are different. In your post, you said you want dates for which Col G is less than -4 or greater than 4. Your image says you want dates where Col H is less than -3 percent or greater than 3 percent. Which is it? Col G or Col H? +/-3 or +/-4? Percent or not?

Comment: I've updated my answer, if this is still not what you want, type an example of what you'd like to see in row M and post a screenshot so we know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:G, "select A where G > 3 or G < -3", 1)
```

Try that in the row where you'd like the dates.

**EDIT**

Still not 100% sure what you want, try putting this formula in Cell M2:

```
=QUERY(A2:I,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I where H>0.03 or H<-0.03",1)
```

That will return the whole table for just the +3%/-3% days.
If you'd just like the date and percentage, use:

```
=QUERY(A2:I,"select A,H where H>0.03 or H<-0.03",1)
```

or for literally just the date, `=QUERY(A2:I,"select A where H>0.03 or H<-0.03",1)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. worked perfectly. This is the data of a stock market index. wanted to see the dates in which it has more than +/- 3% swings.  Thanks .

Comment: Happy to help. thanks for updating with a picture, it made it much more clear.